# Trying to assign OptionButton LinkedCell to cell in other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have groups of option buttons currently with LinkedCells on same worksheet.  All works well but I need to move the LinkedCell assignment to another sheet have not been able to get it to work correctly.  What I have posted below assigns the correct cell but still on the same sheet.

```
    Set t = ws.Cells(rOff + v, 2)
    Set rb = ws.OptionButtons.Add(t.Left + 11, t.Top + 12, t.Width - 22, t.Height - 20)
    With rb
        .caption = rbCapt
        .Name = "Btn" & Trim(Str(i)) & "-" & Trim(Str(b))
        .LinkedCell = Sheets("Administrator").Cells(1001, 4).Address         <----- Here
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `String` representation of the address. The output of `Sheets("Administrator").Cells(1001, 4).Address` does not include the sheet name.

```
.LinkedCell = "'Administrator'!D1001"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you.  I even accidentally left off the secondary quotes around 'Administrator' and it works.

Comment: You don't need the `'` if there are no spaces in the sheet name, but it's safer to include them.

Comment: _.Address does not include the sheet name_ - it does if you tell it to. `.Address does not include the sheet name(0, 0, , 1)`

Comment: @chrisneilsen - perhaps poor wording on my part, I meant `.Address` as used by OP (w/o any parameters) does not include the sheet name. I'm aware of the `External` parameter but that did not seem to work here, guessing due to the inclusion of the workbook name.

Comment: @bigben, yeah I know that _you_ know.   Just want to avoid leaving traps for future readers.  An edit might be in order...